# Fourier Sine series uses the orthogonal set $\{\sin(nx)\}^\infty_{n = 1}$ on $0 \le x \le \pi$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, normed-spaces, orthogonality

I came across the following explanation:

> The Fourier Sine series uses the orthogonal set $\{\sin(nx)\}^\infty_{n = 1}$ on $0 \le x \le \pi$.
>
> Here, the norm squared is
>
> $$|| \sin(nx) ||^2 = \int_0^\pi \sin^2(nx) \ dx \\ = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi (1 - \cos(2nx)) \ dx \\ = \frac{1}{2} \left[ x - \frac{\sin(2nx)}{2n} \right]^\pi_0 \\ = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

What does it mean to say that the Fourier Sine series uses the orthogonal set $\{\sin(nx)\}^\infty_{n = 1}$ on $0 \le x \le \pi$? And how did they get and why is the norm squared $|| \sin(nx) ||^2 = \int_0^\pi \sin^2(nx) \ dx$?

I would appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\mathscr{L}^2$ norm on $[0,\pi]$ is
$$ \Vert f \Vert_{\mathscr{L}^2} = \left(\int_0^\pi |f(x)|^2 \,dx\right)^{1/2}. $$
It is induced by the $\mathscr{L}^2$ inner product
$$ \langle f,g \rangle_{\mathscr{L}^2} := \int_0^\pi f(x)\overline{g(x)} \,dx. $$
One usually works in $\mathscr{L}^2$ when dealing with Fourier series because $\mathscr{L}^2$ is a Hilbert space, so it makes sense to speak about orthogonality and similar things.

The set $\{\sin(nx)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is orthogonal because
$$ \langle \sin(nx),\sin(mx) \rangle_{\mathscr{L}^2} = \int_0^\pi \sin(nx)\sin(mx) = 0 $$
whenever $n \not= m$.

Now you can see directly from the above that
$$ \Vert \sin(nx) \Vert_{\mathscr{L}^2}^2 = \int_0^\pi \sin^2(nx) \,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}. $$
Note that this shows that the set $\left\{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sin(nx)\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is orthonormal.

Comment: Be careful. Your stated norm is only a semi-norm. You have to take the quotient of all functions constant zero almost everywhere. In fact, if you do so, $\{\cos(nx),\sin(mx)\}_{n \geq 0, m>0}$ is even a Hilbert basis of $L^2[0,\pi]$. That's why the Fourier series works.

Comment: Of course, I always feel that it is understood that we are talking about the quotient spaces when $\mathscr{L}^p$ spaces are in question.

Comment: Yeah, I forget that all the time to mention aswell. :D

Comment: Thanks for the response. :) When you say $\mathscr{L}^2$ scalar product, you're referring to the inner product, right?

Comment: Yes, I will update that! I always thought that they were synonyms, but I guess that inner product is a more general concept, so it's better to call it the inner product.